Removing borders and toogling between nested cards
I have some nested cards from bslib that I want to toggle between. One of them also has a header. I tried using shiny::conditionalPanel but the result were not good, it left a big empty space. I instead decided to nest several card and give the outer one an id. This works fine, but I would really like to remove the border of the outer layer and also the border of the card which has two cards.
The header function works as expected, but I have essentially assigned it 2x with the same ID. Will it work like this?
library(bslib)
library(bsicons)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

card_header <- card_header(
  "Setting",
  popover(
    bsicons::bs_icon("gear"),
    pickerInput(
      "choose_letter", "letter", inline = TRUE,
      choices = letters
)))


ui <- page_fillable(
  useShinyjs(),
  layout_sidebar(
    sidebar = sidebar(
      pickerInput("a", label = "Select", choices = c("A", "B"), options = list(size = 10)),
    ), card(id = "A", layout_columns(
      col_widths = c(12, 12, 12),
      row_heights = c(1, 2, 1),
      card(
        card_body(
          layout_column_wrap(
            width = 1/2,
            card("A"),
            card("A")
          )
        )
  ),
  card(card_header(card_header), "A"),
  card("A")
)),

card(id = "B", layout_columns(
  col_widths = c(12, 12, 12),
  row_heights = c(1, 2, 1),
  card(
    card_body(
      layout_column_wrap(
        width = 1/2,
        card("B"),
        card("B")
      )
    )
  ),
  card(card_header(card_header), "B"),
  card("B")
))

)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$a, {
    print(input$a)
    lapply(c("A", "B"), function(letter) {
      toggle(id = letter, condition = letter %in% input$a)
    })
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$choose_letter,{
    
    print(input$choose_letter)

    updatePickerInput(session = session, "choose_letter", selected = input$choose_letter)
    
  }, ignoreNULL = TRUE, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Please run shiny::devmode() before starting the app. You'll get a client error for a duplicated ID (invalid HTML). Furthermore, I'd suggest using a hidden tabsetPanel to create the dynamic parts of the UI as shown here.

To toggle between nested cards, add action button in your sidebar:
layout_sidebar(
    sidebar = sidebar(
      pickerInput("a", label = "Select", choices = c("A", "B"), options = list(size = 10)),
      actionButton("toggle","Toggle Cards")
    )

Then in your server:
observeEvent(input$toggle,{
    toggle("A")
    toggle("B")
  })


